# How to add a custom block to cart sidebar in magento 1.9x

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, template

I created my custom CMS block in Magento, with identifier info_cart.
I changed the checkout.xml file and the cart page now has to 2 columns with right sidebar (instead of 1 column).

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

I also added this piece of code

```
<reference name=checkout.cart>
  <block type=cms/block name=info_cart>
     <action method=setBlockId><block_id>info_cart</block_id></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Which displays the content from the custom block. But the content is displayed at the bottom of the page, not in the sidebar, on the right side of the page. Where should I put `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_cart'); ?>` to be display on the right sidebar instead of bottom of the page?

**EDIT:**
I update the text with the full cod of checkout.xml

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <label>Shopping Cart</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb"><crumbName>home</crumbName><crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title></crumbInfo></action>
            <action method="addCrumb"><crumbName>shopping_cart</crumbName><crumbInfo><label>Shopping Cart</label><title>Shopping Cart</title></crumbInfo></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
                <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                    <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                </block>

                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Form Before</label>
                </block>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                    <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                    <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
                </block>

                <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.replace.crosssell" as="replace.crosssell" translate="label">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sample Block Replace With Crosssell</label>
                </block>
                <block type="themeframework/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>

                <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" translate="label">
            <label>Additional Product Info</label>
        </block>

        <reference name="right"> <!-- or left, whatever -->
        <block type="cms/block" name="info_cart">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>info_cart</block_id></action>
        </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: See My edit in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code

```
<reference name="right">
  <block type=cms/block name=info_cart>
     <action method=setBlockId><block_id>info_cart</block_id></action>
 </block>
</reference>
```

Right block has `core/text_list` type of block so you dont need to write `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_cart'); ?>`

**Edit**

In your handler `checkout_cart_index` comment out below code

```
<remove name="right"/>
<remove name="left"/>
```

The above code responsible not to load left and right section

Comment: First I tried your suggestion but didn't work. The content from the custom block doesn't appear at all when I change reference name to right. Instead if the reference name is checkout.cart, the content is visible at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Can you please show your full code

Comment: I pasted the whole code from checkout.xml. I don't understand why it formats it so bad...

Comment: @raduc. got the problem you are adding `reference ` with in `reference ` add direct in `checkout_cart_index`

Comment: Commenting out <remove name="right"/> did the job! Thank you!

Comment: @raduc. you are always Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a block in left side bar using this code:

```
<reference name="left_first"> <!-- use left_first instead of left for rwd theme-->
<block type="cms/block" name="info_cart" >
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>info_cart</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Comment: I want the content from the info_cart to be visible only on the cart page. If I add the code you provided won't it display the content everywhere on the website?

Comment: You can put this on checkout. Xml. Do some effort yourself

Answer (score 0):

Define this xml in local.xml

```
<reference name="right">
  <block type=cms/block name=right_cart>
     <action method=setBlockId><block_id>right_cart</block_id></action>
 </block>
</reference>
```

Then create a block with id 'right_cart' in admin.

Refresh the cache to view results.